# Wix Uninstall failure, Error 0x80070057, on BootstrapperApplication.PlanComplete

Tags: wix

I get the following error code 0x80070057 on `PlanComplete` event when trying to uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was not calling `Engine.Detect()` on Uninstall when `BootstrapperApplication.Command.Action == LaunchAction.Uninstall`.

In any case you must call `Detect()`, even if you know exactly what you intend to do.